# Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed while copying data

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using the following query:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.StudentDestination') IS NULL
    begin
     Select *,getdate() MyTimeStamp 
     into AkshayDestination..StudentDestination 
     From AkshaySource..sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) 
    End
    Else 
    Begin
     Insert into AkshayDestination..StudentDestination 
     select   *,getdate() MyTimeStamp
     From AkshaySource..sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) 
    End
```

That's basically a way to copy all data in a table to other table (with one time-stamp column added to determine the time of insertion)

But it's giving me one error:

```
Msg 4122, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed.
```

Please let me know where am I wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems pretty self-explanatory to me. One potential workaround would be to create a stored procedure on the remote server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT *,getdate() MyTimeStamp
     From sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL);
END
GO
```

Then on the local server:

```
Insert into AkshayDestination..StudentDestination 
  EXEC AkshaySource.databasename.dbo.whatever;
```

Another idea is to use dynamic SQL:

```
Insert into AkshayDestination..StudentDestination 
  EXEC AkshaySource...sp_executesql N'SELECT *, GETDATE()
    FROM sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL);';
```

Comment: I liked the second approach. Please note that the destination table may not exist. In that case the table should get created before filling up the data(with time-stamp). Other wise if the table already exists, it should simple fill up the data (with time-stamp). When I ran the dynamic sql, it gave me this error when the tables does not exist: "Invalid object name 'AkshayDestination..StudentDestination'". Can you please edit your dynamic sql to take care of this.

Comment: @AkshayJ Why don't you create the table once, and then truncate it before use? I don't see why - after the first time the code runs - you'd ever need to worry if the table doesn't already exist. So just create it. There isn't an easy way to make either of my queries create the table first without using ugly things like `OPENQUERY/OPENROWSET`. So, if that's not good enough for you, *shrug*.

Comment: It's basically to make the code dynamic. I used "Select *,getdate() MyTimeStamp 
     into AkshayDestination..StudentDestination 
     From AkshaySource..sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) " in my code earlier and that did the job. Can you do something similar ?

Comment: *sigh* I *could* but I really don't feel like that dynamic solution is necessary. After you've created the table once, why would you ever need to check again if it has been created? It's already there! Who's deleting tables in your system?